# Following along with iTunes U - Creating the Slider App in CS106B using Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode3to4

I am following along with the first video in the iTunes U course, and the instructor creates a slider app that I am trying to replicate on my system, unfortunately I am using a different version of Xcode than what is being used in the video, thus making it difficult to follow along.  I have the slider and the label setup in my app, and I created the "MyController" object, but I can't figure out how to create the link between the "MyController", Slider, and Label.  In the video he creates two outlets while the "MyController" is selected, but I can't figure out how to do this in Xcode 4, as he is using Xcode 3.  Then he creates an action.  If anyone has any thoughts or ideas on how to get this done, I would appreciate it.

Basically when the slider is moved, it should update the label "number". I wish I could provide a link to the video, but I'm not sure if that is possible since I accessed the video via iTunes.

The video can be viewed at the following link
https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By right clicking on a UI element in my scene I was able to drag a wire from the UI element (slider) to the appropriate view controller file. I setup an IBAction to update the label when the slider was moved by right clicking on the slider and dragging to the View Controller.  With the necessary outlets and action setup I was able to update the label when the slider was moved.